# gatsby react-bootstrap carousel wont work

Tags: carousel, gatsby, react-bootstrap

getting this error code on the gatsby local host where the webpage is suppose to be:
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

   ```
   import React from "react"
    //import { Link } from "gatsby"
    import Layout from "../components/layout"
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import slide01 from "../images/slide01.jpg"
    import { Carousel} from 'react-bootstrap';

    const IndexPage = (props) => (
      <Layout>
            <Carousel>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img src={slide01} alt="before and after" />
                </Carousel.Item>
            </Carousel>
      </Layout>
    )

    export default IndexPage
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time (almost 100%) that this error occurs is because you are loading more than one instance of the `react-dom` package. This means that you installed the React dependency and another dependency also uses React as an internal package causing a multiple loading.

Take a look at your `package.json` to check your dependencies.

In addition, you can find useful [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3965) because exposes a bunch of different errors, its casuistics, and possible solution for each case that may suit your issue.

Comment: it only gives me the error when i place the carousel in there though. could that still be the case?

Comment: Yes, indeed that's why I'm saying. Can you provide the `package.json`? Take a look at the GitHub's thread.

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "gatsby": "^2.24.54",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.4.17",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.4.28",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.2.27",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.10",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.32",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.28",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.5.14",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0"

Comment: I think there's a missmatch between `react-boostrap` and your React (and `react-dom`)  version itself. Did you install an specific version of any of those packages? Can you run `npm ls react` and `npm ls react-dom` to check both versions?

Comment: $ npm ls react
gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 C:\Users\zeek\desktop\splash2.0
+-- gatsby@2.24.54
| `-- gatsby-cli@2.12.92
|   `-- react@16.13.1  deduped
`-- react@16.13.1

Comment: $ npm ls react-dom
gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 C:\Users\zeek\desktop\splash2.0
`-- react-dom@16.13.1
No nothing specific at all. i just installed them through git bash

Comment: Both are at `16.13.1`, isn't it? Try upgrading the `react-bootstrap` package.